# Why `setTimeout` call more than one time when I use `useState`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm so confused about `useState` in React hooks.

I do not know why `console.log` in setTimeout function calls more than one time when I use `useState`.

If I remove `useState` it normally calls only once.
And If I use Class state instead hooks, it normally calls only once as well.

Why is it happened that ?
And how can I handle it ?

(here is my code)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const usePassword = () => {
  const [passwordValue, setPasswordValue] = useState({
    password: "",
    passwordHidden: "",
  });
  let timer = null;

  const trigger = () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => console.log("end"), 1000);
  };

  const onPasswordChanged = (name, value) => {
    setPasswordValue((prev) => ({ ...passwordValue, passwordHidden: value }));
    trigger();
  };

  return { passwordValue, onPasswordChanged };
};

function App() {
  const { passwordValue, onPasswordChanged } = usePassword();

  const onChanged = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    onPasswordChanged(name, value);
  };
  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log("submitted!", passwordValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <input name="password" onKeyUp={onChanged} />
        <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you set the state using `useState` you get a new `timer` variable, as the function is called again. This is why your `clearTimeout` does not work.

You can use a `ref` to hold on to the value between render cycles:

```
 const timer = useRef(null);

  const trigger = () => {
    clearTimeout(timer.current);
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => console.log("end"), 1000);
  };
```

[image: Edit competent-goldstine-jbt3t]

Comment: Oh! God Thanks!! You save my life. Anyway, Can you explain to me why if I use `setState` it call once normally. https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-grothendieck-8rju3?file=/src/App.js